# I have broken packages/ dependencies problems and nothing will fix it

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to download Nvidia, and it won't let me.

It says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
Nvidia-390:
 Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have broken packages.
```

I have tried everything on the internet I could find and would really appreciate new ideas

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using?  How did you try to install the nvidia driver?

Comment: @ubfan1 I am using 16.04 I did                                                                     sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update                                                                       
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375(and other versions) <- here is where the error happens

Answer (score 2):

Nvidia 384.111 is the (tested) driver in the standard repositories for Ubuntu 16.04.  There is no need for using the graphics-drivers ppa to get a later version at this time.  Revert back to the standard packages with:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

There were so many "graphics-drivers" ppas from various sources in the past, check /etc/apt/sources.list.d for any unwanted ppas (just delete the file and rerun sudo apt-get update).

Then list and remove any installed nvidia packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

Installed packages are on lines beginning with "ii"

```
sudo apt-get purge <the installed nvidia packages>
```

Check that all the blacklist lines were removed from all the files in /etc/modprobe.d.  Comment them out if necessary.
Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And now run the Software and Updates from the launcher, and under the Additional drivers tab should be the Nvidia 384.111 (tested) driver.
Select that, and apply.  Reboot and check that you are running the correct driver with the Nvidia Settings (from the launcher).

Comment: I don't have any Nvidia stuff on my computer as of now sudo ppa-purge doesn't work neither does dpkg -l | grep nvidia

Comment: Good that no nvidia packages show up in dpkg -l, try the ppa-purge graphics-drivers again, I fixed a typo, left out repository.

Comment: it does a bunch of stuff then says Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ppa:graphics-drivers 
ppa:graphics-drivers

Comment: I don't use ppa-purge myself, and I'm having trouble understanding the man page, try  sudo  ppa-purge -p graphics-drivers

Comment: That didn't work either it just brought me to the help for ppa-purge                 what do you think is wrong with my machine

Comment: How would you do it?